# How to automate the task in Task Scheduler if it is in remote machine?

Tags: c#, asp.net, api, remote-desktop, taskscheduler

I am looking for a way through which 
 
**1.** I can check the status of the task in **Task Scheduler** which is in **Remote machine.**
 
**2.** Also if the task is not running then instead of running it **manually** I want to automate it so that with a button click it will start running so as to avoid login to that remote machine and run it manually.

Is this possible to do? Please help me with your suggestions and answers? Is it possible to do this using any API in ASP.Net?

Comment: Depends on the setup of the machine running the code and the machine you are going to set the task up on. Are they both on the same domain and do you have the remote WMI ports unblocked on the machine with the schedueller?

Comment: No code will be on a local machine and the task will be on a remote machine. But I want to handle the task from local machine. I mean the status of the task I want get through local machine. Is it possible?

Comment: The "local machine" will be the ASP.NET server which hosts the website you are managing the task from, not the client connecting to the website. Are you trying to control a task on the ASP.NET server or on a different machine?

Comment: I am trying to do it from a different machine. Not from ASP.NET server which hosts the website.

Comment: Yes, and the machine that you are "doing it from" **does not matter** at all. All that matters is the ASP.NET server and the server that is going to have the scheduelled task. Now I am going to ask for the last time: ***Is the computer running the ASP.NET server and the computer running the scheduelled task the same computer, if they are not are they on the same domain?***

Comment: Yes @ScottChamberlain they are on the same domain.